# How to get js-mode to properly indent continued (compound?) var declarations?

Tags: javascript, emacs

If I use distinct `var` statements like

```
function stretchDiv(){
    var wh = $(window).height();
    var sz2 = wh - ((paddingTop + paddingBottom) + (mainTop + 2) * 2);
    // the scrollbar happens only when the height of the elt is constrained
    var sz3 = sz2 - outTop - 2;
    $('#out').css({'height': sz3 + 'px'});
}
```

then [JSLint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSLint) complains, telling me to combine the second and third with the previous.

[image]

If I follow that advice, JSLint is happy, but Emacs' builtin js-mode.el (Emacs v23.2) does not indent the additional `var` declarations the way I want. Also, it does not do the font-lock on the additional variables. See:

```
function stretchDiv(){
    var wh = $(window).height(),
    sz2 = wh - ((paddingTop + paddingBottom) + (mainTop + 2) * 2),
    // the scrollbar happens only when the height of the elt is constrained
    sz3 = sz2 - outTop - 2;
    $('#out').css({'height': sz3 + 'px'});
}
```

[image]

How can I get the proper indentation and font-locking?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A [forked version of js2-mode](https://github.com/mooz/js2-mode) does exactly what you want.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately on the latest edition of emacs (23.2) you can't use the hacked version, because it prevent emacs from automatically starting javascript mode.

Comment: euh, bummer. As a workaround, I defined some mods to the built-in JS mode to teach it to do what I want.  I don't have the syntax highlighting right, but I do have the indentation working. Halfway there.