# JavaScript indentation for var blocks using built-in javascript-mode

Tags: javascript, emacs, elisp

I get the following:

```
   var 
   a = 5,
   b = 6, 
   c = foo();
   /* code continues */
```

I want:

```
   var 
       a = 5,
       b = 6,
       c = foo();
   /* OUTDENT, code continues */
```

I know as per [How to get js-mode to properly indent continued (compound?) var declarations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337649/how-to-get-js-mode-to-properly-indent-continued-compound-var-declarations) there is some hack for js2-mode which gets it done. I would like to know how to do it with javascript-mode (the built-in one, into emacs 24). "var" should indent one level until the first semicolon after var. Comma-first-style should not alter that.

Ideally, I could have it in my init.el, which I could then sync to every computer I am working on. Is that possible? How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put `a = 5` on the same line as `var`. Otherwise, there's no mode that supports this.
2. Use Emacs trunk. The bit of indentation code from `js2-mode` that does this has been committed to `js-mode` just recently, and it was too late for `24.3`. Alternatively, just use a recently released Emacs, and copy `js.el` from the Emacs source tree to a directory in your `load-path`.

Comment: I have compiled emacs trunk, and it works (--version says 24.3.50.1).  Thanks.